# Why is my font color setting not working?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've tried this:

```
#ambrosia h3
{
    font: 12px/18px Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

and this:

```
#ambrosia h3
{
    font: 12px/18px Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

but I still end up with a gray font on my H3 text.

Why?

Comment: `color: red;` should work (`font-color` is incorrect). There may be other styles in your stylesheet overriding it. Also check your HTML that `h3` really exists in an element with `id="ambrosia"`. If you do `color: red !important;` and it works, then you know some other rule is the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely have *other* CSS that has a more specific selector that's giving your `<h3>` that font color, identifying that selector and/or posting your markup would help us provide a more specific selector that *would* override the font color.

Answer (score 4):

Either you have another color set for the id `#ambrosia` and that is taking precedence over the generic selector, or you have another tag inside the h3 which has a color assigned to it.

Or, in your html you have the #ambrosia applied to the `h3` tag, but in your css, you have specified an  h3 element which is *inside* an #ambrosia element. If you are wanting to use `<h3 id="ambrosia">`, your css should be

```
h3#ambrosia { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use Chrome's "Inspect Element" option.
Right click on the line and choose Inspect Element and it will show you the path of the CSS evolution of your element.

Answer (score 0):

the color: red; syntax is correct. however it is possible that you have some other styles in your css file that are conflicting.

you might try using the "firebug" firefox plugin. it will allow you to select the element and see exactly which style is applied to the element and if your class is being overridden